# How to use Boilerplate on Business Catalyst as it does not allow Web server configuration

Tags: html, .htaccess, webserver, boilerplate, business-catalyst

I want to use [Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) for my Adobe Business Catalyst Template. Every thing is fine but it(BC) do not allow .htaccess file as its an hosted solution. What alternatives are there to go without .htaccess file?

I also posted on official Business Catalyst Support Forum but all in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't Boilerplate just a HTML/CSS/JS framework? Why do you need access to .htaccess? You should just be able to FTP it across to your BC site and use it. By the way, BC doesn't allow access to .htaccess, but you don't need it in this case.